# Странности текстового редактора в исходном файле kernel.cu

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cuda, редактор

Подключил **CUDA 8** к **VS2015** по инструкции в документации. После создания проекта в исходном файле **kernel.cu** в текстовом редакторе весь код имеет белый цвет обычного текста. Никаких подчеркиваний ошибок также нет. Но при этом все работает. Если нет никаких ошибок, то код собирается и запускается. А если есть, то только в окне вывода после попытки сборки я об этом и узнаю. Где что и как мне нужно сделать, чтобы все стало на свои привычные места?

Comment: это известная бага в студии, тоже однажды сталкивался с этим, быть может в новым версиях cuda плагина и msvc уже что-то изменилось. Я у себя это не правил, но костыльные решения есть

Comment: Если есть хоть какое-то, то уже хорошо. Можно ли узнать его? А то он работает как обычный блокнот. Нет никакой помощи в редактировании, к которой уже привык. А обычное гугление мне не помогло. Либо гуглил неправильно, либо ничего нет по этой проблеме.

Comment: может vs2019 попробовать?

Comment: @user7860670 , CUDA 8.0 не поддерживает VS версии выше 2015. В тоже время моя видеокарта не поддерживает драйвера для работы с CUDA  9.0+, которые спокойно работают с более новыми версиями студии.

Comment: cuda visual studio intellisense - ключевые слова

Comment: @punchel , благодарю. Буду решать свою проблему доступными методами.